# Gradle dependency resolution always trying mavenCentral first?

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a dependency chain that contains javax.jms:jms:1.1. In maven central, there's a POM for that artifact, but the jar appears to be missing (a problem with maven central). However, we have a local repository that contains the artifact we need. So, I think it would merely be as simple as putting our local repository first, then mavenCentral() last:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://local-maven:12345/repo' }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

However, when running gradle -i, we can see it looks at mavenCentral first. Because it finds the POM on mavenCentral, it doesn't look at any other repository, but then because the jar is missing, the build fails:

```
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar]
....
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 'unzipDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'compile'.
   > Could not download artifact 'javax.jms:jms:1.1:jms.jar'
      > Artifact 'javax.jms:jms:1.1:jms.jar' not found.
```

So why is it looking at mavenCentral first? Why isn't it looking at my own maven repository first? If it did, the problem would be solved because it would find javax.jms:jms:1.1:jms.jar just fine... but I can't see a way of forcing that.

Answer (score 4):

Repositories are searched in their declared order. My best guess is that you didn't publish a POM to your local repository, and that's why the search continues. So either fix that, or tell Gradle that some modules in Maven Central have their artifacts in your local repository:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        artifactUrls "http://local-maven:12345/repo"          
    }
}
```

Comment: The POM is definitely in the local-maven. If I remove mavenCentral() entirely, it works (as long as I remove the other dependencies that are only in maven central, of course). I don't want to redefine the artifactUrls because not every dependency is in local-maven, so I do still depend on maven central for some things.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing all the details. Anyway, artifactUrls configures *additional* artifact URLs. It's specifically designed for the use case where Maven Central only contains a module's POM. And it will still find everything in Maven Central.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser exactly this solved an issue with jms-1.1.jar for me. I added `"https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public"` as an `artifactUrl`.
@Depressio kindly accept Peter's answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Due to licensing issues the JMS jars were removed from maven central. If you are using a newer version of Gradle you may be able to specify a different gradle repository as the exclusive provider of the JMS jars. This will allow the rest of your dependencies to be pulled from maven central without error.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    exclusiveContent {
        forRepository {
            maven {
                url "https://repository.jboss.org/maven2"
            }
        }
        filter {
            // this repository *only* contains artifacts with group "javax.jms"
            includeGroup "javax.jms"
        }
    }
}
```